# Bullet library roadmap

Tags: ros, bullet, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [ROS bullet wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bullet) states the following:

> The version of bullet distributed with ROS currently has patches against the official version of bullet. Our hope is to move towards the official version so that it can be a standard system install.

As far as I can tell, this has been there for a long while. Is there any development with this issue?

I wrote a package in ROS which uses tf::Transform math. I am trying to separate it into a standalone library which can be used outside of ROS. I am not certain what math library to use. I assume there might be problems if I link it to non-ROS bullet, if the library is then used with a ROS wrapper which uses the patched ROS bullet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59612/bullet-library-roadmap/) by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4954 on 2013-03-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of Hydro that Roadmap has been completed.  Bullet is now a system dependency.  The note is out dated, I'll remove it.

The required changes are outlined in the Bullet Changelog.  Depending on where your package is along those lines you should see where you need to update.  http://wiki.ros.org/bullet/ChangeList

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0